# When to use type constraint in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, constraints

According from the typescript doc: [Using Type Parameters in Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints), the code using generic constraint are like this:

```js
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

getProperty(x, "a"); // okay
getProperty(x, "m"); // error: Argument of type 'm' isn't assignable to 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'.
```

However if i try:

```js
function getProperty<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

getProperty(x, "a"); // okay
getProperty(x, "m"); // error: Argument of type 'm' isn't assignable to 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'.
```

It works fine and i do not see any reason why bother using type constraint here.

So when should i use type constraint? Especially for the keyword `extends` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a type constraint (first approach) typescript will be able to infer "non widen" key type. So `key` will be of type `"a"` and not `"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"`.

If this behavior is desired or not depends on specific case, but it looks like your example could benefit from it - the function would be able to resolve property type properly:

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];
}

function getProperty2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    return obj[key];
}

const x = { a: 1, b: '2', c: true };

const v = getProperty(x, "a"); // v is number

const v2 = getProperty2(x, "a"); // v2 is string | number | boolean
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AdVZQCeAPACoA0iA0oqgB5SpgAmAzogNapFzCJkAfAAo4AIwBWALgFVuRGdQCUiAN4AoRIizoQWJOIkBteQF0A3OoC+69aEiwEKdNjwFiAJnIjDMylx4ZeT4BFQ0tHSg9A0kTHgtrWwgENihEekQAXjVEAEMZAEYqMRkAcg9SqggZKCwQVEQrS3VksFTEADcs50wcfEIiYXoqACJckaVzRAB6ac7EGA4wEABbMQIklLSOj260XrcBjyHR8cmZua7FxFSsGDBkRAAfRGW1gmfEMTg4ABtUXJgIA)

Answer (score 0):

With first approach you can do

```
getProperty<typeof x, 'a'>(x, 'a')  // Ok
getProperty<typeof x, 'a'>(x, 'b') //  Error
```

You can specify what exact key of T you want to use.

With secons appeoach you only can use any key of T.